# Dumping and restoring data from/to different versions of Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, backup

I work on a project backed by Neo4j. I'd like to find a way to dump a db and restore it in an inter-version fashion (e.g., dumping data from version `2.*` and loading them to version `3.5.6`, or vice versa!).

What I need is a way to extract and reload data that is supported by as many Neo4j versions as possible. I've checked out external libraries such as APOC, but it looks like they are not available for older versions of Neo4j. In the past, I've also tried to brutally copy data files but this raised errors if Neo4j version are too far.

The best inter-version solution I've found so far is using the REST API of Neo4j as described in [this blog post](https://neo4j.com/blog/export-csv-from-neo4j-curl-cypher-jq/). I perform query like this one

```
curl -H accept:application/json -H content-type:application/json \
  -d '{"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH ... RETURN ..."}]}' \
  http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit
```

to retrieve nodes and rels (as well as their labels and properties) and to serialize them in JSON files. Then, I process such JSONs with a custom Python script to reload data in the new Neo4j db. Of course, eventual indexes or constraints need to be recreated in the destination.

I'm wondering if there is method smarter than the mine to do this, avoiding inter-version hassles.

Comment: Not sure dumping and loading is supported between different versions, but did you check this link?
https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/dump-load/

Comment: Yes, I did. Looks like this is available only for `3.0+`. I am looking for something that can move data intra versions